# How to parameterise a known distribution with mean, standard deviation and fixed upper and lower bounds?

Tags: probability, density-function, truncated-distributions

I am looking for something resembling the normal distribution but which is capped at 0 and some size N. The average can be at any point between 0 and N, and there exists a specified standard deviation. What is this type of distribution called?

Answer (score 3):

There are different distributions that satisfy your criteria. For instance:

- The [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) has support on $[0,1]$, but of course it can be shifted and scaled to any given finite interval. For appropriate parameter values, it is bell shaped.
- The [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) would work. Or more general, a truncated version of any [standard distribution](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm); take your pick. The truncated *normal* is the most common truncated distribution, but the t or the Cauchy are also bell-shaped and can be truncated.

Comment: The [difficulty with these distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/408171/7224) is that the mean (average) of the truncated distribution cannot be set easily as the parameter of the distribution since it is obtained through special functions. Exponential distributions may prove easier to handle.