# Expectation of a positive random normal variable

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $R=X\mathcal{I}(X>0)$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the indicator function and $x \sim N(\mu,\sigma).$

Thus,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[R]&=\mathbb{E}[X\mathcal{I}(X>0)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x \mathcal{I}(x>0) \phi(x;\mu,\sigma)dx \\ &= \int_0^\infty x \phi(x;\mu,\sigma)dx = \int_0^\infty x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{\sigma} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dx.
\end{align}

I then introduce the substitution $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \implies x=\mu - z\sigma$, hence giving us

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[R]&= \int_{-\mu/\sigma}^\infty (\mu + z\sigma)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2}\right) dz \\&=\mu[1 - \Phi(-\mu/\sigma)] +\sigma\phi(-\mu/\sigma) \\&=\mu \Phi(\mu/\sigma) + \sigma\phi(\mu/\sigma) = \mu_R.
\end{align}

Could anyone verify if my calculations are correct? The next step is to calculate the variance, so would like to be certain that this is correct first.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Xi'an compared to this link, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408171/compute-truncated-normal-distribution-with-specific-mean-and-variance, it is different no?

Comment: Update: I drew the sample mean and it turned out correct.